# Android AlarManager Notification repeating

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

In My Android app.. I put a notification.. actually my app is a numerology app.. so I am planning to send a notification from app everyday 01.00 AM that new prediction is available for the user... I am able to send notification using alarm manager. But my problem is whenever user open this notification again notification is coming repeatedly.. But I need notification to be send once in a day. Once user opens the notification no need of coming the notification in the same day. If anyone can help please help. I am giving my code below.

MainActivity

```
AlarmManager am;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Context context=MainActivity.this;


        am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        setRepeatingAlarm();


private void setRepeatingAlarm() 
    {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();



          calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
          calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
          calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
          calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
         // PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
         // intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, intent,0);
         // am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
         //  (1000 * 1000), pendingIntent);
            am.set(1, System.currentTimeMillis(),pendingIntent);
          System.out.println("Calling Alaram...");

    }
```

MyReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 

{
    private final String SOMEACTION = "com.jocheved.alarm.ACTION";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        generateNotification(context,"You have new predictions");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (SOMEACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do what you want here
            generateNotification(context,"You have new Predictions");


        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
          System.out.println(message+"++++++++++2");
          int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
          long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
          NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
          String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
         // String subTitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
          String subTitle = "You have new Predictions";
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DirectCalculation.class);
          notificationIntent.putExtra("content", message);
          PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
          notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

          notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
          //To play the default sound with your notification:
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
          notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
          notificationManager.notify(0, notification);



    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the alarm in `onCreate()`, so every time the Activity starts, it sets an alarm for the current time, which fires immediately, starts the Activity, sets another alarm... over and over again. You should use the `AlarmManager#setRepeating()` method to set the alarm once, with a repeating interval of a day.

```
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, intent);
```

You don't need the call to `setRepeatingAlarm()` each time the Activity is created, so you'll need to determine how you want to keep track of whether it is set.

Comment: Thank you so much! you're a lifesaver. @Mike do you think you could help me here http://goo.gl/MAjgTh